# What is the meaning of R88/70D in this METAR from Ashgabat International airport?

Tags: weather

The following METAR is from Ashgabat airport (UTAA)

> UTAA 071300Z 13006KT 9999 FEW050CB BKN050 BKN100 15/06 Q1013 R88/70D
>   NOSIG

What does R88/70D mean, I couldn't find any references?

Answer (score 1):

I assume it was a typo, as R88/70D is not a correct METAR format. According to [this website](https://www.ogimet.com/display_metars2.php?lang=en&lugar=UTAA&tipo=ALL&ord=REV&nil=SI&fmt=html&ano=2019&mes=03&day=06&hora=16&anof=2019&mesf=03&dayf=07&horaf=16&minf=59&send=send) with historical METARs the METAR of today at 1300Z at UTAA was:

> METAR UTAA 071300Z 13006KT 9999 FEW050CB BKN050 BKN100 15/06
>              Q1013 R88/CLRD70 NOSIG=

All other METARs from UTAA today contain "R88/CLRD70 " as well.

R88/CLRD70 means: all runways are cleared (no more deposits), and a friction coefficient of 0.70.

Comment: My guess: R88: all runways, 70: friction coefficient .70, D: dry.